# What is the meaning of ``it'' among the sentences?

Tags: meaning-in-context

There are several texts below and made a bold mark on the [Verb it that] sequence. What I am interested is whether there is a idiom-like meaning between [Verb it that] sequence. If not, what does pronoun *it* refer to in each sentence..?

---

[Text1]

"No. But it was afraid it might have sinned . '' She pointed at me.

"That is your fault, for **teaching it that** sexual behavior is sinful. But, physiologically, sexual contact between solcetaceans isalways pleasurable for all parties involved."

---

[Text2]

All her life Marilyn " Trish " Robinson Ringell suffered from severe asthma. As a teenager she had to take such strong medicine to **control it that** it would make her slim, just-over-100-pound body so hyperactive that she felt shewas coming out of her skin.

---

[text3]

I don't know. I don't **question it that** stuff keeps on coming back.

---

[text4]

she shut her eyes and chewed the meat of my psyche and refused to let go until it thundered. She **dug it that** I took her to Chez Police, and her digging went down through multiplestrata.

---

[text5]

I think that it is important when the most powerful country in the world looks at an international organization that we need to have somebody that's **heading it that** we believe is suitable to take it into a dynamic new age.

---

[text6]

It is here on Moresby Island and the small islands that **flank it that** the remains of the ancient Haida culture are most evident. The whole southernhalf of the archipelago, called Gwaii Haanas, is a Haida Heritage Site.

---

[text7]

In this particular speech without any reference to what his record was -- and we can certainly talk about that -- he attacked Bush on the war on terrorism and that he's **conducting it that** it's undermining domestic freedom.

Answer (score 1):

text 1: 'it' refers to whatever they are talking about (a creature of some sort)

text 2: asthma

text 3: probably 'it' could be omitted but more context would say for sure

text 4: idiomatic: 'dig it' = 'like it'

text 5: the international organisation

text 6: Moresby Island

text 7: I guess this is from speech as it does not really make sense grammatically. You can tell that 'it' refers to the war on terror, but the phrasing would need correcting to make proper sense e.g. 'and said that he's conducting it in a way that is undermining...' or similar.